# Send upload progress update to client using node.js, node-formidable and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, socket.io, formidable

My code shows a simple upload form (`node-formidable` and `node.js`). I am using `socket.io` to update the client on it's current upload file progress. **My problem is that I currently emit the progress update to every clients.** As an example, if I start an upload with clientA, then connect to the website with clientB, clientB will see the exact same progress bar as clientA. Normally, **clientA and clientB should be different, with their own respective progress bars**, linked only with their respective uploads.

This is my app.js file

```
// Required modules
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util'),
    fs = require('fs-extra');

// Path to save file, server side
var savePath = "./uploadedFiles/";

// Loading index.html
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // Form uploading Process code
    //Upload route
    if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        // creates a new incoming form. 
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

        // set the path to save the uploaded file on server
        form.uploadDir = savePath;

        // updating the progress of the upload
        form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
            io.sockets.in('sessionId').emit('uploadProgress', (bytesReceived * 100) / bytesExpected);
        });

        // parse a file upload
        form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
            res.write('Upload received :\n');
            res.end(util.inspect({ fields: fields, files: files }));
        });
        form.on('end', function (fields, files) {
            /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
            var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
            /* The file name of the uploaded file */
            var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
            /* Files are nammed correctly */
            fs.rename(temp_path, savePath + file_name, function(err) {
                if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
            });
        });
        return;
    }

    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});

// socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join("sessionId");
});

server.listen(8080);
```

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Socket.io</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Test d'upload</h1>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
            socket.on('uploadProgress' , function (progress){
                document.getElementById("currentProgress").value = progress;
            });
        </script>

        <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>

        <p><progress id="currentProgress" value="0" max="100"></progress></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I do not have more code than this. I am new to node.js and socket.io, so I am not sure about the interactions between them and between the client and server.

How can I change my code to update only the right client?

Thank you anyway for your time.

Answer (score 1):

a suggestion 
there is a basic way

```
socketIO.sockets.socket(this.socketid).emit(<event>, dataObj);
```

if your function is inside your socket code...otherwise I will often do something like this

```
connection.query("select socketid from websocket_sessions  where user_id=" + data.form.user_id, function(err, users) {
  socketIO.sockets.socket(users[0].socketid).emit(<event>, dataObj);
});
```

where I am always updating or a

Comment: I tried to use this in my provided code and it did not work. How do you get a user id? Do you have a simply example that fits my code? Thank you.